# coding this function without memory leak! - please advise

Tags: function, c#-3.0, dispose, filestream

In the following code example,will filestream and streamreader get disposed or will they create memory leaks? Is it possible to code this function without causing memory leaks?

```
  string ReadFile(string strPath)
     {
         using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Open))
         {
             using (StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(fstream))
             {
                return sreader.ReadToEnd().ToString(); //NOTE ITS RETURNED HERE...SO CAN IT GET DISPOSED AFTER THIS LINE?
             }
         }
     }
```

Thanks

Comment: As far as I understand .NET, not disposing a filestream will not create a (resource) leak, because it will be disposed by the GC at some point. It's just a good habit to dispose it as soon as possible.

Comment: BTW could I ask why are you doing a ToString() on a string ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`using` directive means:

```
try
{
var iDisposable = new IDisposable();
//using iDisposable...
}
finally
{
//here IDisposable's dispose
}
```

So yes both `fstream` and `sreader` will be disposed.

Comment: but the objects get returned even before dispose is called right?

Comment: Yes, the final string object that resulted from all the operations (the function return value) is fine, even after the objects that generated it get disposed.

Comment: The objects will be returned and then finally block will be called where defined IDisposable, FileStream for example, will be disposed.

Comment: Call order will be : function call, FileStream.ctor, StreamReader.ctor, StreamReader.ReadToEnd, String.ToString, StreamReader.Dispose, FileStream.Dispose, End of function

Answer (score 0):

The `using` directive calls the Dispose() method regardless whether the instantiating method returns within the block or not.

Please note, however, that you could use the `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` method to achieve the same with less code:

```
 string ReadFile(string strPath)
 {
     return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(strPath);
 }
```

Comment: yes,I'm aware of this,but I need to repeatedly access the file to store and read data